# QuartzScheduler hanging while addJob()

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I need a little help.
I am new at using Quartz Scheduler. 
I am trying to register a new job with Quartz Scheduler using addJob method. The program hangs. Below is the thread Dump for the same.

```
OSGi Console" prio=3 tid=0x08230800 nid=0xa in Object.wait() [0x8b41d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimpleSemaphore.obtainLock(SimpleSemaphore.java:94)
        - locked <0xaf6c2310> (a org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimpleSemaphore)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3804)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:93)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3735)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1075)
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.addJob(QuartzScheduler.java:920)
        at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.addJob(StdScheduler.java:269)
        at com.ericsson.oss.utilities.scheduling.manager.SchedulingService.createJob(SchedulingService.java:226)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.ericsson.oss.utilities.scheduling.dao.RetryInterceptor.invoke(RetryInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:160)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy153.createJob(Unknown Source)
        at com.ericsson.oss.utilities.scheduling.cli.commands.CreateCommand.execute(CreateCommand.java:207)
        at com.ericsson.oss.utilities.scheduling.cli.commands.CommandProcessor.execute(CommandProcessor.java:76)
        at com.ericsson.oss.utilities.scheduling.cli.EquinoxCommandProvider._usscheduling(EquinoxCommandProvider.java:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.console(FrameworkConsole.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.run(FrameworkConsole.java:223)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: can you post your code that you have tried?

Comment: you probably have another process that took the db lock, could you check?